# How to set in PHP List's 1 Value depenting on List's 2 Value and the Opposite

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm building a site for educational purposes. 
I am trying to built a tichu counter in PHP and MySQL. 
I have two Lists.
These two lists have values from -25 to 125 and the step is 5. 
If I add these lists, I want to have a sum of 100. I mean, when "Team 1 Score" is 40, "Team 2 Score" must be 60.
 
When I change 1st List Value, I want automatically 2nd List to change too. And the opposite.
When I have select List1 Value, I want List2 Value to be 100-List1 Value but if I change again List 2 Value, then List 1 Value will be 100-List1 Value

My code works fine for now. If I set the Values on my own, I write my score in my db. But I want the scores to be dependent.

I haven't find something helpful but I think that I don't know how to search for it.

I tried to do it with a new table. I inserted my possible values in the same row but I can't handle it.
I have these Sets

[image]

I want t1 and t2 to be displayed in my dropdown lists and when I change List 1, List 2 to take the right value

If you want more details please tell me...
Sorry if My text is awful... It's the first time I write here.
Thanks in advance,
Christos

**UPDATE**
This is the Code I tried to excecute.
First I tried to Display them in different lists but they weren't changing so I did this "List1 | List2" to test my output... This is from test file so, there's no action in my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
    <from action="" method="post">
    <label for="t1">Team Scores:</label>
        <select name="t1" id="t1">
                <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'tichu');
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT t1,t2 From score");
                $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo "<option value='". $row['setted'] ."'>" .$row['t1'] ." | ".$row['t2']."</option>" ;
                }
                 
                ?>
                <br/>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        </body>
```

Comment: Could you please share you code in post.... whatever you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're after, but here's something to think about...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),
(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),
(30);

SELECT id,(id-5)*5 m,100 - ((id-5)*5) n FROM my_table;
+----+-----+-----+
| id | m   | n   |
+----+-----+-----+
|  0 | -25 | 125 |
|  1 | -20 | 120 |
|  2 | -15 | 115 |
|  3 | -10 | 110 |
|  4 |  -5 | 105 |
|  5 |   0 | 100 |
|  6 |   5 |  95 |
|  7 |  10 |  90 |
|  8 |  15 |  85 |
|  9 |  20 |  80 |
| 10 |  25 |  75 |
| 11 |  30 |  70 |
| 12 |  35 |  65 |
| 13 |  40 |  60 |
| 14 |  45 |  55 |
| 15 |  50 |  50 |
| 16 |  55 |  45 |
| 17 |  60 |  40 |
| 18 |  65 |  35 |
| 19 |  70 |  30 |
| 20 |  75 |  25 |
| 21 |  80 |  20 |
| 22 |  85 |  15 |
| 23 |  90 |  10 |
| 24 |  95 |   5 |
| 25 | 100 |   0 |
| 26 | 105 |  -5 |
| 27 | 110 | -10 |
| 28 | 115 | -15 |
| 29 | 120 | -20 |
| 30 | 125 | -25 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Strawberry. But I can't understand what I have to look in your code. I have a static table. I don't want to change these values. I have these 31 rows and I want to display them in 2 lists. my first list has the values of t1 and the second, has the values of t2. I want t2 to take value depending on t1 choise. If t1 is 55 and has setted value 15, t2 has to take value on the same row.

Comment: My point is really that you can easily calculate the values on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

On the MySQL level you may simply use BEFORE UPDATE trigger which checks what value was changed and changes another value accordingly:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_sum_is_100_always
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.t1 = OLD.t1 THEN
    SET NEW.t2 = 100 - NEW.t1;
ELSE
    SET NEW.t1 = 100 - NEW.t2;
END IF;
END
```

This is simplified code - you must additionally check that:

1. None NEW value is set to NULL
2. None NEW value is out of allowed range (-25 .. 125), and they have allowed values (divides by 5 without reminder)
3. Only one value is changed (if both then set which' value has priority)

You must also add complementary BEFORE INSERT trigger for to check/set values for newly inserted rows.

On PHP/HTML level you must requery new value when some value was changed in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Akina. I'm new at SQL but with a fast look at your code, makes sense. I didn't understand what I have to check after that. I mean, I have these 31 possible rows. I will not add more or delete some of them. I want to say that my table is static. Nothing changes. I have these 31 rows and I want to display them in 2 lists. my first list has the values of t1 and the second, has the values of t2. I want t2 to take value depending on t1 choise. If t1 is 55 and has setted value 15, t2 has to take value on the same row.